Using AWS Amplify, I'm trying to find the table name for the dynamodb table that is created with the data/resource. How Can I find that?
I'm trying to find the table name to use the dynamo db that is auto generated using AWS Amplify after creating a schema using 'data'. How can I find that?
Here is what I've tried:
resource.ts file
const schema = a
  .schema({
    UserProfileFlags: a.customType({
      isBetaUser: a.boolean(),
      isFounder: a.boolean(),
      isBanned: a.boolean(),
      isSuspended: a.boolean(),
      isVerified: a.boolean(),
      isDeleted: a.boolean(),
    }),

    UserProfile: a
      .model({
        userName: a.string().required(),
        owner: a
          .string()
          .authorization((allow) => [allow.owner().to(['read', 'delete'])]),
...

to define a database in dynamo named UserProfile. That works fine, the db is created and the table exists. Now I'm trying to create a function to access that table. I've tried many iterations, but they all have errors/won't compile or work:
I found this:
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';
import { getDataSource } from '@aws-amplify/backend-function';
import type { Schema } from '../../data/resource';

const dynamodb = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export const handler: Schema['createEmptyProfile']['handler'] = async (event, context) => {
  const dataSource = getDataSource(context);
  const TABLE_NAME = dataSource.resources.UserProfile.tableName;

This one tells me that import { getDataSource } from '@aws-amplify/backend-function';  is a problem:

Module '"@aws-amplify/backend-function"' has no exported member 'getDataSource'.ts(2305)

I've also tried running this:
npx ampx generate graphql-client-code --out /graphql
and then
import { env } from "$amplify/env/post-confirmation";
...
        endpoint: env.AMPLIFY_DATA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
...

But this too shows AMPLIFY_DATA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT is undefined, and if I look in the generated .ts files, I don't see it either.
That kind of makes sense, since I'm not sure how that would work when deployed, as it needs a different table name. This is all running against a local sandbox.
Here is the docs link that I can find:
https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/functions/examples/create-user-profile-record/

I'm using Gen2. I would think that would be the correct version, but it seems like Gen1 is way more common.
